# Do I need different constant names for different levels of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, constants

I'm just getting my feet wet in integration, so pardon me if I misuse a term.

Let's take the anti-triple-derivative (I'm not sure if that's what it's actually called) of $8x$.

$y'''=8x$

$y''=4x^2+c$

$y'=\frac43x^3+cx+d$

$y=\frac13x^4+cx^2+dx+e$

Now, could (should) I have used $c$ for all of the constants because they could be anything? For example, $y'=\frac43x^3+cx+c$ and $y=\frac13x^4+cx^2+cx+c$. Or are the different constants necessary because the constants are not necessarily the same?

Comment: If you'd like the "$c$" from line 2 to be the same "$c$" as in line 4, then in line 4 it needs that term needs to be $\frac{1}{2}cx^2$. It is also totally accepted practice to just rewrite the arbitrary constant $\frac{1}{2}c$ as $c$ in the last line.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but half of a constant is still a constant, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different constants are necessary because the constants are not necessarily the same. Well done: $y = \frac 13x^4 + cx^2 + dx + e$ is correct.

Comment: That is a lot of constants, but +1 is the best constant! :-)